# Calculation of energy deposition

Tags: nuclear-physics

I currently need a guide on how to calculate the energy deposition on material surface using SRIM/TRIM software.

Comment: SRIM comes with a manual and examples.

Comment: Okay. Thank you Jon Custer. I have downloaded and will read them.